# React setState can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the following warning

> "Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the ContactPage component."

When I initially go to the contact page the firs time it is fine. Then if I navigate off the page and go back the warning is thrown.

Contact page component :

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import AppStore from '../../stores/AppStore';
import AppActions from '../../actions/AppActions';
import DataContent from './DataContent';

const title = 'Contact Us';


class ContactPage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = AppStore.getState();
        AppActions.getData();
    }

  static contextTypes = {
    onSetTitle: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.context.onSetTitle(title);
    AppStore.listen(this.onChange.bind(this));
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    AppStore.unlisten(this.onChange.bind(this));
}

onChange(state) {
    this.setState(state);
}

renderData() {
    return this.state.data.map((data) => {
        return (
            <DataContent key={data.id} data={data} />
        )
    })
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={s.root}>
        <div className={s.container}>
          <h1>{title}</h1>
          <div>
              { this.renderData() }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}

}

export default ContactPage;
```

When I put debuggers in, on load of contact page it hits componentWillMount(). When I leave the contact page it hits componentWillUnmount(). When I navigate back to the page it hits componentWillMount() again and then throws the error when it hits the onChange(state) function.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The issue is that the listener of the previous component instance is still registered. And because the previous instance isn't mounted anymore, you get that error.

`.bind` always returns a **new** function. So if you do

```
AppStore.unlisten(this.onChange.bind(this));
```

then you are trying to remove a listener that doesn't exist (which fails of course). It does *not* remove the listener you registered with `AppStore.listen(this.onChange.bind(this))`

---

To solve this, you should bind the handler *once* in the constructor:

```
this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
```

and then use `AppStore.listen(this.onChange)` and  `AppStore.unlisten(this.onChange)`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Been struggling with it for couple hours.

Comment: @Felix King  can you help me please ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43608401/how-to-disable-only-the-setstate-message-warning-on-react-native                                                                                 https://gist.github.com/Sofiane-13/64d2467dca037dd35bf0dd4d430bdd38

Comment: THANK YOU! this warning has been irritating me for a week. This solved it

Comment: @Felix Kling, I'm getting this warning on multiple components. Do you suggest to do this on each of them for various functions. Isn't there a app wide solution to pursue this?

Answer (score 6):

Before the change, state check component is mounted.

```
render() {
   return (
     <div ref="root" className={s.root}>
       // ----
     </div>
   )};

 onChange(state) {
   if(this.refs.root) {
     this.setState(state);
   }
 }
```

I think this will help to you.

Answer (score 0):

In your case add a ref to your root div and check the ref value before you call setState.

Your `onChange` method should looks like this:

```
onChange(state) {
    this.refs.yourRef ? this.setState(state) : null;    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was struggling with this issue as well for quite a while.

What solved for me was to do as @Felix Kling proposed but also make sure my callback function was declared within the component's class, otherwise you're not able to use the `this` prefix, wich was apparently what did the trick for me.

Here is an example of what I mean:

***Legal, but doesn't work***

```
function onChange() { 
  this.setState({ MyState: newState })
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    onChange = onChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', onChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', onChange);
  }

  render() { ... }
}
```

***Works***

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange() { 
    this.setState({ MyState: newState })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.onChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onChange);
  }

  render() { ... }
}
```

Hope it helps anyone else facing this problem. :)