# setState is not updating object array's value

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to update an object array namely `users` inside `Users` component, using following function:

```
  updateUser = (index, user) => {
    let temp = this.state.users;
    temp[index] = user;
    this.setState({users: temp});
    console.log(this.state.users);
    console.log(temp);
  }
```

Doing that gives me following warning:

> proxyConsole.js:56 Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the Users component.

Log output is as follows:
[image]

**Please Note:**

- This function is called from another component to update a single user from an array of user. But the value **is not persisting** . As soon as I call this function with another/new value old updates doesn't retains.
- My objective is to re-render all the components as soon as array is modified.
  Edit1: I have four components: 
  IE. `Users` component is calling `List` it is calling `User` and it is calling `UserDetail`.

`Users` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import List from './list';
import '../App.css';

class Users extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      users:[
        {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", email: "John@mail.com", company: "Monsters Inc."},
        {firstName: "Tom", lastName: "Riddle", email: "Tom@mail.com", company: "Slytherin Inc."},
        {firstName: "Harry", lastName: "Potter", email: "Harry@mail.com", company: "Gryffindor Inc."}
      ],
      adding: false
    }
  }

  updateUser = (index, user) => {
    let temp = this.state.users;
    temp[index] = user;
    this.setState({users: temp});
    console.log(this.state.users);
    console.log(temp);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.addingMode}>ADD</button>
          <List data={this.state.users} remover={this.remover} updateUser={this.updateUser}/>
        </div>
      );
    }
}

export default Users;
```

`List` component:

```
class List extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{textAlign:"Left"}}>
        {this.props.data.map((profile, i) =>
          <User key={i} id={i} data={profile} remover={this.props.remover} updateUser={this.props.updateUser}/>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`User` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import UserDetails from './userDetails';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';

class User extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editing: false,
      text: ""
    };
  };

  showUserDetails = () => {
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: '/details',
      state: { data: this.props.data, id: this.props.id },
      updateUser: this.props.updateUser
    });
  };

  render() {
    return(
    <div>
      <h4>{this.props.data.firstName}</h4>
      <button onClick={this.showUserDetails}>View</button>
      <button>Remove</button>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(User);
```

`UserDetails` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import User from './user';

class UserDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isEditModeEnabled: false,
      firstName: this.props.location.state.data.firstName,
      lastName: this.props.location.state.data.lastName,
      email: this.props.location.state.data.email,
      company: this.props.location.state.data.company
    };
  }

  editButton = () => {
    this.setState({isEditModeEnabled: true});
  }

  updateButton = () => {
    this.setState({isEditModeEnabled: false});
    //console.log(this.props.location);
    this.props.location.updateUser(
      this.props.location.state.id,
      { "firstName": this.state.firstName,
        "lastName": this.state.lastName,
        "email": this.state.email,
        "company": this.state.company
      }
    );
  }

  editing = (event) => {
    if (event.target.name === "firstName") {
      this.setState({firstName: event.target.value});
    } else if (event.target.name === "lastName") {
      this.setState({lastName: event.target.value});
    } else if (event.target.name === "email") {
      this.setState({email: event.target.value});
    } else {
      this.setState({company: event.target.value});
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isEditModeEnabled) {
      return (
        <div>
          <b>First Name: </b><textarea defaultValue={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.editing} name="firstName"></textarea><br/>
          <b>Last Name: </b><textarea defaultValue={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.editing} name="lastName"></textarea><br/>
          <b>Email: </b><textarea defaultValue={this.state.email} onChange={this.editing} name="email"></textarea><br/>
          <b>Company: </b><textarea defaultValue={this.state.company} onChange={this.editing} name="company"></textarea><br/>
          <button onClick={this.updateButton}>Update</button>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <b>First Name: </b>{this.props.location.state.data.firstName}<br/>
          <b>Last Name: </b>{this.props.location.state.data.lastName}<br/>
          <b>Email: </b>{this.props.location.state.data.email}<br/>
          <b>Company: </b>{this.props.location.state.data.company}<br/>
          <button onClick={this.editButton}>Edit</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default UserDetails;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React setState can only update a mounted or mounting component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35345338/react-setstate-can-only-update-a-mounted-or-mounting-component)

Comment: @edi9999 The above mentioned question doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: Perhaps, you are trying to set a user state which is already unmounted that means your component in which user state is maintained is already unmounted from your view.

Comment: Can you kindly share the rest of your code.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/this-setstate-doesnt-mutate-state-immediately/41278440#41278440

Comment: @AdeelImran kindly see my updated question

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri please see the log screenshot. State is getting updated temporarily. But the update is not persisting. Pls help.

Comment: @PulkitAggarwal pls see my updated question.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Can you please comment where I went wrong? I'm struck here

Answer (score -2):

It might be because `setState` is asynchronous. That means a `console.log()` right after a `setState` gives you false information. Use the `callback` function of `setState` to determine `state` changes:

`this.setState({users: temp}, () => console.log(this.state.users));`

You should share more of your component to determine the real issue you are facing. It's hard to tell what you are really trying to do, since the code snippet you shared points to a asynchronous issue, while your description and warnings point to another.

Comment: I didn't down voted it. But I already know **setState is asynchronous**. Kindly see the screenshot it shows the updated state.

Comment: @noobie Oh it seemed like you didn't (`console.log(this.state.users);)`. I couldn't determine the workflow of your app from a single screenshot and assumed it showed the old `state`, sorry for that. I can't tell what you are doing wrong from your updated code though, sorry.